# How to select only one image at a time among three different rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, siblings

I'm creating color palette and user can select one image at a time.

I'm using click action by using javascript but each row can select one image at a time.

I want to only select one image among those three different rows.

How to do it? Please help.

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

body {
  margin:0;
  color: #FFF;
}

.board-pages {
  position:absolute;
  top:75px;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:calc(100% - 75px);
  overflow:hidden;
}
.board-page {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  transition:all 0.4s;
  transform:translateX(0);
  overflow:auto;
  background-color: #262931;
}

.grid-row-theme .grid-item-theme {
  max-width: 130px;
}

.trending-above-palette {
  padding: 6px;
}

#align-left {
  float: left;
  color: #747474;
}

#align-right {
  float: right;
  color: #9CC8E3;
}

.grid-item {
  flex:0 1 25%;
  padding:6px;
}

.grid-item-theme {
  flex:0 1 25%;
  padding:6px;
}

.grid-row {
  overflow-x:auto;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

.grid-row .grid-item {
  display:inline-block;
  max-width:110px;
}

.grid-item-content {
  text-align:left;
  font-family: "mr-eaves-modern";
  font-size:0.7rem;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}


.pick-palette img{
  border: 3px solid #FFF;
}

#dropdown-menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2% 0 6% 0;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Omnibag Project</title>
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
</head>
<body> 


<div class="board-pages">

      <div class="board-page">

        <div class="grid-item-theme" id="dropdown-menu">Warm<i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_down</i></div>

        <div class="trending-above-palette">
          <div class="grid-item-theme" id="align-left">Trending</div>
          <div class="grid-item-theme" id="align-right">See all</div>
          <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div>   

        <div class="grid-row">
          <div class="grid-item grid-beige">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />   
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Beige
              <!-- <i class="material-icons more-icon">more_horiz</i> -->
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-camel">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Camel
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-salmon">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Salmon Pink
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-navajo">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Navajo White
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-niagara">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Niagara
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-primrose">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Primrose
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-lapis">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Lapis Blue
            </div>
          </div>


        </div>
        

        <div class="after-first-palette">
          <div class="grid-item-theme" id="align-left">Newly added</div>
          <div class="grid-item-theme" id="align-right">See all</div>
          <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div> 


        <div class="grid-row">
          <div class="grid-item grid-pale">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Pale Blue
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-moss">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Moss Green
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-melon">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Melon
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-chiffon">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Chiffon
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-island">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Island
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-dogwood">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Dogwood
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-greenery">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Greenery
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
        

        <div class="after-first-palette">
          <div class="grid-item-theme" id="align-left">All Warm Colors</div>
          <div class="grid-item-theme" id="align-right">See all</div>
          <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div>    
        <div class="grid-row">

          <div class="grid-item grid-ivory">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Ivory
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-honeydew">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Honeydew
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-lavender">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Lavender
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-canary">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Canary
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-hazelnut">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Hazelnut
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-kale">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Kale
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-sharkskin">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content sharkskin">
              Sharkskin
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://use.typekit.net/hoc0zbs.js"></script>
  <script>try{Typekit.load({ async: true });}catch(e){}</script>

  <script>

    $(".board-pages .grid-item").on("click",function(){
      $(this).addClass( "pick-palette" ).siblings().removeClass("pick-palette");
    });
 

  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that way for example

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

body {
  margin:0;
  color: #FFF;
}

.board-pages {
  position:absolute;
  top:75px;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:calc(100% - 75px);
  overflow:hidden;
}
.board-page {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  transition:all 0.4s;
  transform:translateX(0);
  overflow:auto;
  background-color: #262931;
}

.grid-row-theme .grid-item-theme {
  max-width: 130px;
}

.trending-above-palette {
  padding: 6px;
}

#align-left {
  float: left;
  color: #747474;
}

#align-right {
  float: right;
  color: #9CC8E3;
}

.grid-item {
  flex:0 1 25%;
  padding:6px;
}

.grid-item-theme {
  flex:0 1 25%;
  padding:6px;
}

.grid-row {
  overflow-x:auto;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

.grid-row .grid-item {
  display:inline-block;
  max-width:110px;
}

.grid-item-content {
  text-align:left;
  font-family: "mr-eaves-modern";
  font-size:0.7rem;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}


.pick-palette img{
  border: 3px solid #FFF;
}

#dropdown-menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2% 0 6% 0;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Omnibag Project</title>
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
</head>
<body> 


<div class="board-pages">

      <div class="board-page">

        <div class="grid-item-theme" id="dropdown-menu">Warm<i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_down</i></div>

        <div class="trending-above-palette">
          <div class="grid-item-theme" id="align-left">Trending</div>
          <div class="grid-item-theme" id="align-right">See all</div>
          <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div>   

        <div class="grid-row">
          <div class="grid-item grid-beige">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />   
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Beige
              <!-- <i class="material-icons more-icon">more_horiz</i> -->
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-camel">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Camel
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-salmon">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Salmon Pink
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-navajo">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Navajo White
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-niagara">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Niagara
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-primrose">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Primrose
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-lapis">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Lapis Blue
            </div>
          </div>


        </div>
        

        <div class="after-first-palette">
          <div class="grid-item-theme" id="align-left">Newly added</div>
          <div class="grid-item-theme" id="align-right">See all</div>
          <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div> 


        <div class="grid-row">
          <div class="grid-item grid-pale">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Pale Blue
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-moss">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Moss Green
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-melon">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Melon
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-chiffon">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Chiffon
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-island">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Island
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-dogwood">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Dogwood
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-greenery">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Greenery
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
        

        <div class="after-first-palette">
          <div class="grid-item-theme" id="align-left">All Warm Colors</div>
          <div class="grid-item-theme" id="align-right">See all</div>
          <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div>    
        <div class="grid-row">

          <div class="grid-item grid-ivory">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Ivory
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-honeydew">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Honeydew
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-lavender">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Lavender
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-canary">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Canary
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-hazelnut">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Hazelnut
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-kale">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content">
              Kale
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item grid-sharkskin">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" alt="" class="grid-item-img" />     
            <div class="grid-item-content sharkskin">
              Sharkskin
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://use.typekit.net/hoc0zbs.js"></script>
  <script>try{Typekit.load({ async: true });}catch(e){}</script>

  <script>

    $(".board-pages .grid-item").on("click",function(){
      $(this).parents('.board-page').find('.pick-palette').removeClass("pick-palette");
      $(this).addClass( "pick-palette" );
    });
 

  </script>
```

1. Find and remove class from previous active image.
2. Add class to clicked image